# Will a screen reader pronounce the colon in HTML label tags?

Tags: html, forms, accessibility

I am wondering if one of these is a better pratice than the other:

```
<label>Foo</label>:
<label>Bar:</label>
```

Is one of these better for accessibility? Does a screen reader read the colon in both cases?

Regards,

Comment: It probably doesn't matter. You can even have the entire input field as a descendant of the label along with the label text, and AT doesn't seem to mind. With that in mind, I would at least include the colon within the label text for the sake of cleanliness.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `:after` to add the colon using CSS, and then that leaves just the label text to be inserted into the tag? This might be better for semantics?

```
<label>Your label here</label>

.label:after {
    content:":";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j7cqw6wg/

Comment: I like this way because you won't forget it anywhere

Answer (score 2):

Some screen readers do read certain symbols. A good thing about adding colons is that, generally, screen readers will pause their speech after them. This can be used for controlling the reading pace or whenever you'd like to separate text or put emphasis on it.

Take a look at http://webaim.org/techniques/screenreader/

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a tangent but if you're going to have labels for your fields, you either need the `"for="` attribute in your `<label>` tag or you need to nest your `<input>` field inside the `<label>` tag.

```
<label for='foo'>my label</label>
<input id='foo'/>

<label>my label <input/></label>
```

This will allow the screen reader to read the label when the focus goes to the input field.

As far as the colon, if a colon is in the middle of a paragraph, then as santialurralde said, the reader will pause briefly.  Similar to what it does when it hits a period.  If your colon is on the label (using the format of the examples above), the label becomes the accessibility name of the input field.  The reader usually pauses between saying the accessibility name and the type of element it is so the colon doesn't make much difference.

That being said, I can turn on an option in JAWS to have it read all the punctuation.  I'll hear 'colon' and 'period' and 'comma', etc.  That's not on my default.